# How to handle jquery array for an asp.net mail list?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, email

I've been struggling about this over two days finding solution. I have form, with inputs, selects and multiple select (email adressess) form is parsed by ajax call to controller, saved to DB and then is email sended. What i need to do is use the list of email adressess from multiple select as an list for mail function. I can't find a suitable method to access the json array in controller to use it as described.

I have tried a multiple methods of converting given data to an array for the mail method, but with no luck.

Ajax form handling and sending to controller:

```js
    $("#save").click(function () {
            var notifySelection = $('#notification option:selected').toArray().map(item => item.value);
            var Data = {
                Place: $('#area').val(),
                Part: $('#part').val(),
                NokRange: $('#nokRange').val(),
                Amount: null,
                Warehouse: null,
                Failure: $('#failureCode').val(),
                ResponsibleQPB: $('#responsibleQPB').val(),
                ResponsibleLOG: $('#responsibleLOG').val(),
                BlockDate: currDate,
                BlockedBy: $('#person').val(),
                CusSupp: $('#csName').val(),
                Description: $('#description').val(),
                EndDate: endDate,
                Notifications: JSON.stringify(notifySelection)
            }                
            SaveEvent(Data);
        });

        function SaveEvent(Data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../PartBlocking/SaveNewCase",
                data: Data,
                traditional: true,
                success: function (Data) {
                    if (Data.status) {
                        window.location.replace("http://somepage/PartBlocking/SuccessfulySaved")                            
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Uložení se nezdařilo!');
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is controller:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveNewCase(PartBlockingModel addNew)
    {
        var status = false;
        var Part = addNew.Part;
        var Date = addNew.BlockDate;
        var Blockedby = addNew.BlockedBy;
        var Place = addNew.Place;
        var Description = addNew.Description;
        var Notifications = addNew.Notifications;

        //This is how i've tried handle the array at last try
        //string emails = Notifications;
        //string[] email = emails.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 

        db.PartBlocking.Add(addNew);
        int saved = db.SaveChanges();

        //notifaction
        if (saved > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                string body = string.Empty;

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplates/NewCase.html")))
                {
                    body = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                body = body.Replace("{Part}", Part);
                body = body.Replace("{Date}", Date);
                body = body.Replace("{BlockedBy}", Blockedby);
                body = body.Replace("{Place}", Place);
                body = body.Replace("{Description}", Description);

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

                var sub = "SAPNo | Díl č. - " + Part;

                var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp"],
                    Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["portnumber"]),
                    EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsSsl"]),
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
                };

                mail.From = new MailAddress("postmaster@email.com", "Evidována nová neshoda");
                mail.To.Add("xx@email.com");
                mail.To.Add("xy@email.com");
                //This is how i've tried handle the array at last try
                //foreach (var item in Notifications)
                //{
                //    mail.To.Add((item).ToString());
                //}
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Subject = sub;
                mail.Body = body;

                smtp.Send(mail);
                status = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = ex;
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status } };
    }
}
```

And model:

```
public class PartBlockingModel
{
//rest of definition for db
......
......
//definition for notifications
public string Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

The data are correctly inserted into db and if I use only predifinied emails via mail.To.Add("xy@email.com"), email is sended correctly. What i need is to  use Notifications list given by jquery as an email list for MailMessage method.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, make sure you javascript object "Data" is the same structure as C# object "PartBlockingModel"

your ajax request must be as the followinf :

```js
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../PartBlocking/SaveNewCase",
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(Data),
                traditional: true,
                success: function (Data) {
                    if (Data.status) {
                        window.location.replace("http://somepage/PartBlocking/SuccessfulySaved")                            
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Uložení se nezdařilo!');
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, I've modified my ajax call as you suggest, but still no luck. I've checked via console how are data from multiple select served to an ajax call. Output from a console: ["xx@email.com","xy@email.com"], in a same way they are stored in database.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

In my jquery data binding i've changed

```
Notifications: JSON.stringify(notifySelection)
```

to:

```
Notifications: notifySelection.join(',')
```

and now in my controller works my solution for listing emails as desired and sendig to email addressess from input.

```
string[] email = Notifications.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var item in Notifications)
            {
                mail.To.Add((item).ToString());
            }
```